# Python function NameError

Tags: python, function, nameerror

I am using python 3.4.1. I keep getting this error,

```
 (NameError: name 'calcHullSpeed' is not defined)
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
import math

LWL = float(input("Enter the length of the boat: "))
maxHullSpeed = calcHullSpeed(LWL)
print("The hull speed is: " + str(round(maxHullSpeed,2)))

def calcHullSpeed(LWL):
    maxHS = 1.34*math.sqrt(LWL)
    return maxHS
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your function first:

```
def calcHullSpeed(LWL):
    maxHS = 1.34*math.sqrt(LWL)
    return maxHS

LWL = float(input("Enter the length of the boat: "))
maxHullSpeed = calcHullSpeed(LWL)
print("The hull speed is: " + str(round(maxHullSpeed,2)))
```

Functions have to   be defined **before** you call them.

Comment: Just as do variables too...

Comment: Just like in C (when not using a headerfile).